# how to program neon register index

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I have a 8x8 data. After processing, I want to keep resulting 8x8 data for time being for further
process. My question is if it is possible to program 4 Q-registers to store them by loop. But the following code doesn't compile,  I also like to increment 12 of d12 to d13

```
mov r4, #7

1:
.
.
vmul.i16 d12, d12, d1[r4] 
subs r4, r4, #1
bge 1b
```

Is there any way or efficient way to handle these?

Comment: I don't understand your question. This discussion of matrix multiplication may get you on the right track for this kind of problem: http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/241-coding-for-neon-part-3-matrix-multiplication/

Comment: I have no problem to calculate matrix, I need to store intermediate results in other 4 Q-registers, that means I need to change Q-registers to store data in a loop.

Comment: I read it three times, still didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can refer to a register indirectly. You probably want to use a macro for this. See the matrix multiplication page I sent for an example of the kind of macro you'd use. You'd call it once for each calculation rather than using a loop. This also has the advantage of avoiding the loop in the first place. If you're using registers rather than memory, I assume you're concerned about the performance, and branches are bad for performance.

Do note the "Scheduling" section in that page as well. If you're very concerned about performance, even macros introduce some problems. If you read and write to the same register quickly (d12 in this case), you can stall the pipeline. You often want to interleave your iterations so that you can avoid this. (..., read from d3, write to d2, calculate using d3, read from d4, write to d3, calculate using d4, ...) That means a lot more hand-written code, but it's much faster.